# Negative infinity to square equals positive infinity?

Tags: limits, infinity

Is $$
 -\infty^2 
$$
 always positive just like for ex.

$$
 (-2)^2 
$$
is always positive?

Comment: I think you want parentheses around that $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function "approaches negative infinity", then the square of that function "approaches positive
infinity", yes.

And if you are doing operations on the extended real numbers, then the answer is still yes.